# Facebook doesn't work on computer, but work on mobile device, both use the same router

Tags: networking, router, facebook

I have a very strange problem and I'm thinking that can be problem with dns or something similar, but not sure and don't know how to solve.

My computer is connected to router and every site works fine except facebook (Chrome and Firefox). Chrome shows "Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset."

But, on mobile device witch is connected to the same router facebook works fine (Fb application and Delphin browser). Pinging facebook works fine.

Clearing cookies and cache didn't help. Also, I performed antivirus and antimalware scan and there is nothing.

What can be a problem?

Update: 
I'm also connect notebook on that wifi router, and on it works fine.

```
nslookup facebook.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    facebook.com
Addresses:  2a03:2880:2110:3f01:face:b00c::
          2a03:2880:10:1f02:face:b00c:0:25
          2a03:2880:10:8f01:face:b00c:0:25
          69.171.224.37
          69.171.229.11
          69.171.242.11
          66.220.149.11
          66.220.158.11
```

Comment: Open a command shell and do an nslookup on facebook.com and see what IP it resolves to. So 'nslookup facebook.com'

Comment: I'm just updated question with nslooup response.

Comment: Try doing a ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: More importantly, what is the error message that appears when you try to access facebook

Comment: still nothing. Chrome needs too long to respond and then show connection error message.

Comment: Try just doing a renewal on your network adapter - ipconfig /renew if you are on DHCP, if not, just disable and re-enable the Network adapter.

Comment: Still nothing. Rebooting also didn't help... :(

Comment: Can you give us more info on how you preformed the antivirus/antimalware scans?  What error are you getting in IE and Firefox?

Comment: This is an interesting one - can we get some more thorough malware scans on there - something like malwarebytes and superanti-spyware. Also, do you get the same error in other browsers?

Comment: I scanned computer with Nod32 and Malwarebytes. I can give you a logfile, but there is nothing special - object detected is 0. IE and Firefox are still trying to load page after 5 minutes (Status bar: Waiting for https://www.facebook.com/...).

Comment: Maybe I have good news, sometimes page is loaded, but after very long waiting time (in other devices this is permanently). But after minute or two, nothing works. Here is screenshot of firefox with request https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34111231/firefox.png

Comment: check if by some mistakes a proxy is active in either Chrome, Firefox, or IE

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **https://www.facebook.com** instead http://www.facebook.com

Some tips: [How to fix the problems with Facebook on Google Chrome?](http://www.chromefans.org/chrome-tutorial/how-to-fix-the-problems-with-facebook-on-google-chrome.htm)

Comment: I'm always use https for facebook. Didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe facebook.com is redirected in your hosts file?

Open it with a text editor and check for any lines that mention facebook.com. You can find the file [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system).

Comment: Nice point, but hosts file is ok also.